# How to pin explorers properly in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to pin the "Properties" bar that way.

[How i want it to be pined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv86J.png)

[when closing VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTAqw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basicly in my case:

pin the solution explorer to right,
tnen pin the properies to the solution explorer's bottom

Yeah, that is it, but firstly wasn's seem that easy.
Piece!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).